# How do I download aspnetboilerplate specific template version?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

Is it possible to download aspnetboilerplate specific template version ?

Comment: It's there in the Template page https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates. Is that what you eant?

Comment: I want to download template include abp version 2.3.0. is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can download using this Repo, https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/tree/v2.3

Checkout  tag v2.3.0, and to rename the project u can use aspnetboilerplate rename script